# api запрос jQuery.ajax

Tags: javascript

Не могу разобраться почему не работает

```
var ip = '134.201.250.155'
var access_key = 'a88cf1b48d330ffd4298c132d3b5ce13';

// get the API result via jQuery.ajax
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.ipstack.com/' + ip + '?access_key=' + access_key,   
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {

        // output the "capital" object inside "location"
        console.log(json.location.capital);
        
    }
});
```

Источник https://ipstack.com/documentation
Запускал https://jsfiddle.net/GRMule/WQXXT/

Answer (score 0):

Если выполнить данный код:

```
var ip = '134.201.250.155'
var access_key = 'a88cf1b48d330ffd4298c132d3b5ce13';

fetch(`http://api.ipstack.com/${ip}?access_key=${access_key}`)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data =>
{
    console.log(data);
})
```

Видно, что возвращает ошибку: `Access Restricted - Your current Subscription Plan does not support HTTPS Encryption.`.